# XML or CSV for "Tabular Data"

Tags: c++, c, xml, parsing, csv

I have "Tabular Data" to be sent from server to client --- I am analyzing should I be going for CSV kind of formate or XML.

The data which I send can be in MB's, server will be streaming it and client will read it line by line to start paring the output as it gets (client can't wait for all data to come).

As per my present thought CSV would be good --- it will reduce the data size and can be parsed faster.

XML is a standard  -- I am concerned with parsing data as it comes to system(live parsing) and data size.

What would be the best solution?

thanks for all valuable suggestions.

Comment: CSV can be read line after line (client wants to parse it as it comes). XML will have to wait for the ending `</data>` tag. If you own both server and client, you can use CSV.

Comment: @eumiro: I would think that SAX parsers are *meant* for streams.

Comment: @Matthieu M Yes definitely we can use SAX parser it solves the problem of reading in real time but even SAX return only after node ends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CSV, with a header which indicate the id of each field.

```
id, surname, givenname, phone-number
0, Doe, John, 555-937-911
1, Doe, Jane, 555-937-911
```

As long as you do not forget the header, you should be fine if the data format ever changes. Of course the client need be updated *before* the server starts sending new streams.

If not all clients can be updated easily, then you need a more lenient messaging system.

Google Protocol Buffer has been designed for this kind of backward/forward compatibility issues, and combines this with excellent (fast & compact) binary encoding abilities to reduce the message sizes.

If you go with this, then the idea is simple: each message represents a line. If you want to stream them, you need a simple "message size | message blob" structure.

Personally, I have always considered XML bloated by design. If you ever go with Human Readable formats, then at least select JSON, you'll cut down the tag overhead by half.

Comment: I have tried in one of my parser CSV header it is very handy to identify the column index --- this can make your parser to work in the case if there is some change in coleman too. I will study  
Google Protocol Buffer to know how better they have implemented this.

Answer (score 4):

If it is "Tabular data" and the table is relatively fixed and regular, I would go for a CSV-format. Especially if it is **one** server and **one** client.

XML has some advantage if you have multiple clients and want to validate the file format before using the data. On the other hand, XML has cornered the market for "code bloat", so the amount transfered will be **much** larger.

Comment: WRT bloat, there are excellent streaming compression libraries (gzip) which helps a bit... though I obviously never recommend XML, there are always more suited alternatives.

Comment: Compression complicates the process at both ends, but is almost required for handling high volumes. The upside is that "bloat" compresses well. :-)

Comment: compression take more processing ... even I can apply it to CSV too to get the same benefit ....

Comment: @Girish: it does, but you may need it anyway.

Comment: @Matthieu M yes I need it ... it is part of communication layer in my solution ...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you go for XML.
There are plenty of libraries available for parsing.
Moreover, if later the data format changes, the parsing logic in case of XML won't change only business logic may need change.
`But in case of CSV parsing logic might need a change`

Comment: As @Matthieu M. stated if we parse header in CSV we can have clear logic to parse even in future changes(Basically you need column identification logic using header)

Answer (score 0):

CSV format will be smaller since you only have to delare the headers on the first row then rows of data below with only commas in between to add any extra characters to the stream size.