# Make tabular Data downloadable as a CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a website which offers data in standard HTML table form and is displayed across 7 columns. At the backend, data is stored in MySQL and displayed through PHP on the webpage.

Site visitors have been demanding that data be made available for download in a CSV file, and I am OK to offer that feature.

What is the best way to offer a limited number of columns (say 3 out of 7 columns) with a one-click download into CSV file?

*Note: this question is **NOT** about site visitors **scraping** data using python or other scripts, but it is about a webmaster willingly offering the option to download data in a CSV file.*

*Searched for and checked this thread [XML or CSV for "Tabular Data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881243/xml-or-csv-for-tabular-data), but it does not have a precise answer, hence the question.*

Comment: What is your backend stack?

Comment: @Newbie - as I mentioned, At the backend, data is stored in MySQL.

Comment: We need more info.  What programming language are you using to interface with MySQL?  I've done almost exactly this, for example, with Perl.

Comment: @polyhat Its PHP and MYSql combo

Comment: I don't know how with PHP.  With Perl, one can fork the process and return a zip file for download to the browser using a package like IO::Compress::Zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new PHP file (page) that instead of rendering the content as HTML will render it as a CSV. Then manipulate response headers to make clear to the browser that it is a file meant to be downloaded. This is how your `.php` file should look like:

```php
<?php

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');

    // ... QUERY FOR DATA

    $outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
      fputcsv($filehandler, $vals, ',', '"');
    }
    // CSV header
    __outputCSV(['header1', 'header2', ...]);
    // CSV body
    array_walk($data, '__outputCSV', $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);

?>
```